# python: using glob from specific directory

Tags: python, wildcards

I am using glob function to load

```
#make a list from pdb filles located in the same directory as this python script
pdb_list = glob.glob('*.pdb')


# do something on each pdb file
for pdb in pdb_list:
  some_variable = some_function(pdb)
```

How could I use specific path for glob, e.g. to load all of these pdb filles directly from some specific sub-directory, located at the same place with my python script and then return to the initial directory (to produce there some outputs)?

```
The one way that I found is to use
# change current directory to ./pdb
os.chdir("pdb")
```

however, in this case everything (including saving of the results) will happens within this directory contained all of the initial PDB filles. Is it possible rather to indicate that glob looks for the filles inside pdb folder but staying always within the initial place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob` also works with relative paths so you can simply use `pdb/*.pdb` and it will work -- `glob` will return results relative to your current directory:

```
>>> glob.glob('test/*.txt')
['test/c.txt', 'test/b.txt', 'test/a.txt']
```

And if you need the result without the directory you can always use `os.path.basename` to get just the filename:

```
>>> [os.path.basename(p) for p in glob.glob('test/*.txt')]
['c.txt', 'b.txt', 'a.txt']
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, the second example with list comprehension creates proper list of the filles (without its path). However, in order to process the filles in for loop using some functions, I have to go into the PDB directory using os.chdir("pdb"), right? I would rather prefer to stay always within the "root (with my python script)" directory, in order that I could take all input filles from the PDB folder and saving all the results into another folder RESULTS. Presently RESULTS folder appears in the folder PDB so both input/output are mixed ..

Comment: It depends on what you are going to do with the files, but you shouldn't need to use `os.chdir` because functions like `open` will work with a relative path too so you can use `open('test/c.txt', 'r')` without changing the directory.